# SQL Conditional Select Help (Amazon Redshift SQL)

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, amazon-redshift

I currently have 2 queries that I am trying to merge into 1. Basically I want to pull previous days sales if it's Tuesday - Friday and the previous 3 days sales if it's Monday. My queries are below - is there a way to do a conditional select for those date based on the day of the week?

Monday's version

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHEN  DATE_TRUNC('day', timestamp) IN (CURRENT_DATE - 1, CURRENT_DATE - 2, CURRENT_DATE - 3)
  AND DATE_PART(weekday, current_date) = 1
```

Tuesday - Friday version

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHEN  DATE_TRUNC('day', timestamp) = CURRENT_DATE - 1
  AND DATE_PART(weekday, current_date) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

one solution is :

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE DATE_TRUNC('date', timestamp) <= DATE_TRUNC('date', CURRENT_DATE)
AND DATE_TRUNC('date', timestamp) >= case when DATE_TRUNC('day of week',CURRENT_DATE)  = 'Monday' then DATE_TRUNC('date', CURRENT_DATE - 3) else DATE_TRUNC('date',CURRENT_DATE) end
```

Comment: you are welcome , please accept / upvote  the answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

You can use `OR:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
WHERE (DATE_TRUNC('day', timestamp) IN (CURRENT_DATE - 1, CURRENT_DATE - 2, CURRENT_DATE - 3) AND
        DATE_PART(weekday, current_date) = 1
       ) OR
       (DATE_TRUNC('day', timestamp) = CURRENT_DATE - 1 AND
        DATE_PART(weekday, current_date) <> 1
       )
```

This can be slightly simplified to:

```
WHERE timestamp > CURRENT_DATE -
                  (CASE WHEN DATE_PART(weekday, current_date) = 1 INTERVAL '3 DAY'
                        ELSE INTERVAL '1 DAY'
                   END)
```

Note:  This assumes that there are no future timestamps.

Comment: So I don't want it to pull both I want it to pull one or the other. If it's Monday pull the previous 3 days if it's Tuesday - Friday pull just yesterday. I probably didn't clarity that in the initial question.

Comment: @zscheimer . . . That is what this logic does.  The `date_part()` condition is only going to match once.